# How to allow a case to run N times

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

I'm running some C++ code on an SDK that uses a switch statement for whenever particular events occur. I am working on the case that occurs when the signal strength of a bluetooth signal changes and it will report the new value back. I only want this to report back N times instead of continuously however, how could I achieve this?

```
case BLE_GAP_EVT_RSSI_CHANGED:
    sd_ble_gap_rssi_get(p_ble_evt->evt.gap_evt.conn_handle, &RSSI);
    printf("\nRSSI =%d dBm", RSSI);
    break;
```

Comment: You could add a counter that increments every time that case is hit. Once N is reached you can either break/return or have the print statement in an if statement.

Comment: Next time, post text as text, please, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1):

```
static int rssi_changed_counter = 0;

switch( /* ... */ ) {
// ...

case BLE_GAP_EVT_RSSI_CHANGED:
    if(rssi_changed_counter < N) {

        // ...

        ++rssi_changed_counter;
    }
    break;

// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not about bluetooth, or signals, or about making a `case` run *N* times.

This is about *deactivating a piece of code* after some condition has been met.

Your condition is that your code has been run through already, *N* times.

You want your code to do something different on the *N+1<sup>th</sup>* time (and, presumably, thereafter).

The best way to do this depends on code that we cannot see. It could be as simple as a counter and `if` statement. It could be the de-binding of a function pointer. It could be the removal of an event trigger from some third-party library. The choice is yours.